# Principal ideal of $\mathbb{C}[Z,\bar{Z}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ideals

Let $I$ be an ideal of $\mathbb{C}[Z,\bar{Z}]$.

> How to prove that $I$ is principal in  $\mathbb{C}[Z,\bar{Z}]$ ?

It exists some simple criterion to say that an ideal will be principal or not?

Comment: What are $Z$ and $\overline Z$?

Comment: $Z$ is the indeterminate and $\bar{Z}$ is the complex conjugate of $Z$, but you can think about them as simple $[X,Y]$

Comment: An ideal in the polynomial ring is principal if and only if it its reduced Groebner basis consists of one element.

Comment: @MooS there is no other thing than Gröbner basis ?

Comment: If you want a general method to find out whether some general ideal of the polynomial ring satisfies some property, it always boils down to Groeber bases, doesn't it?

Comment: yes but the calculation of such basis is very difficult, and more if we have only a abstract description of the ideal

Comment: With two variables, we also have the following: If $I$ is reduced, $I$ is principal if and only if each irreducible component of $V(I)$ is one-dimensional. But how do you (in general) compute the irreducible components without Groebner bases? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an ideal $I=(f_1,\dotsc, f_s)$ in a noetherian factorial ring and let $f$ be the greatest common divisor of the $f_i$.

> Then $I$ is principal if and only if  $f \in (f_1, \dotsc, f_s)$
>   holds.

In practice, working in the polynomial ring, figuring out whether this holds, you need Groebner bases.

Thus, in practice, you can also directly use the following equivalence:

> $I$ is principal if and only if its reduced Groebner basis consists of
>   one element.